# Add contacts to android only if app is installed

Tags: android

I want to add a list of contacts to a user's Android phone only if my app is installed on their device and then remove it when my app gets uninstalled. How do I approach this problem? Do I have to use Java? Can I tackle it through flutter?

Comment: Take a look at [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service)

Comment: @RickyMo, I did see that, but it's not what I wanted. I want to do something like the sync service which adds contacts when you add an account but then are removed when the account is unlinked from the device.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get any callback when user uninstalls the application so removal of contacts is not possible. But yes you can add new contacts when the user installs the application check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) link.